# What does a function array syntax in go mean?

Tags: go

```
var list = []func(*someType) error {
        ...
    }
```

I am new to Go and I am trying to understand what does the syntax mean ? 
Is the return of function an array?

Comment: You read Go code from left to right like normal english (not in spirals like C or kinda backwards like Java). `[]` "slice of" `func` function, `(` "from argument", `*` pointer to, `someType` "someType", `)` "returning an", `error` "error". Could not be much simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This declares and initializes a variable `list` as a [slice](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7) whose elements are functions with signature `func(*someType) error`.

Slices in Go are convenient mechanisms for representing sequences of data of a particular type. They have type `[]T` for any element type `T` (but remember Go does not have generics). A slice is defined only by the type of the items it contains; its length is not part of its type definition and can change at runtime. (Arrays in Go, by contrast, are of fixed length - their type is `[N]T` for length `N` and element type `T`).

Under the surface, a slice consists of a backing array, a length of the current data and a capacity. The runtime manages the memory allocation of the array to accommodate all data in the slice.

Answer (score 1):

`func` in go is a type like `int`,`string`...

So they are sample syntax:

```
var listInt := []int{1,2,3}
var listStr := []string{"1","2","3"}
var listFunc := []func(param anyType) anyType {
    func(param anyType) anyType { ... return new(anyType) },
    func(param anyType) anyType { ... return new(anyType) },
}
```